# How can I open a file (excel, txt, word) listed in a ListBox in an App published on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've developed an WebForms app in which I have files from a folder listed in a ListBox. Running in VS2019 works fine, I double click the name of the file in the listBox and it opens but when I publish it to IIS on a Windows Server 2012, It just opens the procces on the backgroud but the file never opens.

I changed the account which the app runs to LocalSystem, Power Domain Users and nothing happens. Also I gave username and password to Process.start.

```
 var folder1 = @"\\BOXI\Ejecutables\CRM2\" + NumCaso_txt.Text;

                foreach (char c in "PASSWORD")
                    pwd.AppendChar(c);
                if (Directory.Exists(folder1))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder1);
                    FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
                    {
                        //filesLbox.Items.Add(FI.Name + " " + FI.CreationTime);
                        if (filesLbox.SelectedIndex == i)
                        {

                            ProcessStartInfo procStart =
    new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe", FI.FullName);
                            procStart.UserName= "USER";
                            procStart.Domain= "DOMAIN";
                            procStart.Password = pwd;
                            procStart.UseShellExecute = false;
                            Process.Start(procStart);
                            //command.StartInfo.FileName = FI.FullName;
                            ////Process.Start(FI.FullName);
                            //command.Start();
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I'd say the first thing is to make sure that the file paths you're using are valid.

Comment: @Symon Hello, the paths are valid, running the app on VS2019 works.

Comment: May be try with more generic like Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\fileName.doc");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open file on client computer, you need to apply some javascript which could comunicate with OS through browser.

If you want to open file on server computer, your web app must be running on user which has active GUI session. To do this, login to your server using your credentials, change application pool identity to logged in user, restart IIS and the process should open with GUI as you expected. If that doesn't work you can also try enabling "Allow service interact with desktop" option in IIS service configuration.

Comment: Hi, I want to open it on client computer, can you guide me ? And I tried what you said about the server and it doesn't work